# C# - Call/Implement Rest Web Service in Windows Service

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, wcf, windows-services

I'm currently programming a Windows Service with Topshelf (in a Console Application) and I want to implement/call a REST Web Service in it.

I'm using a REST API from a DMS. What my code does is it simply downloads a file from the DMS and returns true or false based on if it downloaded succesfully.

I'm relatively new to all that stuff and I want to learn more.

Is it even possible to do this?

And if so, can you explain to me how and/or link me to some resources? I read about WCF but I have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to call a REST service, you use HttpClient or a wrapper library for said REST service. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @CodeCaster So I have a project including both the Windows Service and the WebService. Let's say I want to trigger a web method inside my WebService.asmx with my console application (Windows Service) every 5 seconds to download that file. Is that possible?
I tried adding the WebService as a service reference in Visual Studio. Then, instantiating a new object in my console applicaction and calling the method from my WebService.asmx with specific parameters but I get the error message "System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: This is what I tried basically: https://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/creating-and-consuming-a-web-service-in-c-net/

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what parts you have and what parts you want to build. I can tell you that that 2017 tutorial about ASMX should have never been written, ASMX was dead way before that. Anyhow, if you have existing code and it gives an error, show that code and that error along with your reseach in your question.

Comment: If you have found the answer, you can post an answer so that people with similar questions can learn from your answer.

Comment: You shouldn't use _TopShelf_ as a means to creating Windows Services (WS) as it teaches bad habits.  Their pipeline of _["Topshelf makes it easy to create a Windows service, `test` the service, `debug the service`, and `ultimately install` it into the `Windows Service Control Manager` (SCM)"](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/faq.html)_ is naive.  The "service" you are debugging is a console app and far removed from a WS to be useful.  Any debugging or testing results are questionable and the code likely to fail (due to security errors) when you finally run it as a WS-proper.